# Suppose $G$ is a group and $|G|=p^k$ , and $X$ is finite set. Let $G$ act on $X$ or the cardinality $|X|$

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

While studying group theory I came across this question:

> Suppose $G$ is a group and $|G|=p^k$ for some $p$ prime number and $k$ integer, and $X$ is finite set. Let $G$ act on $X$ if $p$ does not divide $|X|$ see if $G_{\alpha}=G$ for some $\alpha \in X$ true or not.

I need a hint the relation between the cardinality if $X$ and order of the group $G$. In other words why does the number of elements in $X$ matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

Use the [orbit-stabilizer theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbit-stabilizer_theorem).

If $G$ acts on $X$, then every point $x \in X$ has some orbit. Moreover, since every element is in exactly one orbit we see

$$|X| = \sum_{\text{orbits}} |\text{orbit}|$$

By the orbit-stabilizer theorem, though, we know each orbit satisfies
$|\text{orbit}| \cdot |\text{stabilizer}| = |G|$.

If $|X|$ is *not* a multiple of $p$, but each $|\text{orbit}|$ must divide $|G| = p^k$, what does this tell you about the size of some orbits? It might be helpful to work mod $p$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^